# Using AutoIt to click a button on a window

Tags: bots, autoit, buttonclick

Which function should I use in order to click a pop button after running a program? For example, the league of legends launcher button is what I want to simulate the click.

Answer (score 9):

You can use either [MouseClick](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm) if you know the coordinates of where to click:

```
MouseClick("left", x, y)
```

Or you can use [ControlClick](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm) to click on a specific button:

```
ControlClick("Window title", "", "[classname provided by AutoitINFO]")
```